# how can i convert my sympy code to symengine in python

Tags: python, sympy, symengine

This code I wrote in Sympy is running slow. I want to write this with symengine. How can I translate? I had some difficulty with the Solve commands. Can you help me ?

**Edit:** Here is my code:

```
import sympy as sy
import time
#import numpy as np
import math as mat
from sympy import Eq


testere_capi=197
dis_sayisi=78

ic_acisi = 16
sirt_acisi = 8
derinlik_carpani = 0.4
kucuk_daire_carpani = 0.25
buyuk_daire_carpani = 0.8
son_dogrunun_carpani = 0.06
tas_kalinligi = 2.0

T = ((testere_capi * mat.pi) / dis_sayisi) # hatve
H = T * derinlik_carpani  # derinlik


x = sy.symbols("x")
y = sy.symbols("y")


D2 = sy.Eq(y, H)

a8 = 0
b8 = 0

m_d1 = mat.tan(mat.radians(90 - ic_acisi))
D1 = sy.Eq(y - b8, m_d1 * (x - a8))
S1 = sy.solve((D2, D1), (x, y))
a1 = S1[x] 
b1 = S1[y]


b2 = T * kucuk_daire_carpani
a2 = b2 / mat.tan(mat.radians(90 - ic_acisi) / 2)
r1 = T * kucuk_daire_carpani
D3 = sy.Eq((x - a2) ** 2 + (y - b2) ** 2, r1 ** 2)


D1 = sy.expand(D1)
D3 = sy.expand(D3)
S7 = sy.solve((D1,D3),(x,y)) 
a7 = S7[0][0]
b7 = S7[0][1]
```

Comment: SymEngine can not directly replace the solve function from SymPy but there are likely other ways to speed things up e.g. you probably want to use nsolve rather than solve.